# Execute code in Visual Studio on schedule and automatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have web app code in VS2010 that is manually executed every night. One of the developers manually runs the code in VS, when the web page opens, presses a few buttons etc.. and executes the code to get our required results. How can we automate this process so as to eliminate any human element. Ideally, I am looking for a way to have the code execute automatically at a given time during the day. What is involved in getting something like this to work?

Answer (score 1):

A WCF service is a possible solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows has scheduled tasks which is good at... scheduling tasks.

Do you (or plan to) have a big test of GUI tests?  There are entire tools dedicated to GUI automation testing.  I'd recommend looking into one of those if this is going to be a big part of your overall test strategy.

If this is a one-time thing, you could schedule the running of a simple C# application that hosts a Web Browser control, that points to your web site.  In this sense, the Web Browser control acts as your browser.  You can send JavaScript commands to it etc.

Web Browser documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Another alternative is to schedule an AutoHotKey script to simulate the key pressing and mouse clicks.  This works well.  I used to use it to rack up Farmville points (no joke).

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 1):

A Windows service seems better in the sense of "scheduled" and "no intervention."  A WCF service is still, by default, listening and waiting for interaction (hosting the service).  Or just schedule a simple app or script to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us a little more about this process?  My initial recommendation would be to transition that code from a web application into a command line utility and then use [windows task scheduler](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Working-Windows-Server-2008-Task-Scheduler-Part1.html).  If for some reason there are heavy dependencies within that web app that make that impossible I would consider taking those button click events and turning them into web services that you could then call programmatically from a command line application.

Comment: How do I transition code to a command line utility? can you please provide more information on this.. links etc.. thank you

Comment: Well it depends largely upon how dependent your code is upon other code in your Application.  The command line utility would still be c# so if it's pretty independent it could largely be a cut and paste job. If there are a lot of dependencies you might have to bring in an unacceptable amount of the common functionality.  If this is the case, and command lines really seem like the way to go to you, you could start taking that common code and split it off into a code library that is shared between the web application and the command line.  That way the code only exists in one place.  [Continued]

Comment: Here's your basic hello world tutorial, not fancy, but if you're already well versed in C# you'll see it is trivial to start making it do more complex things. http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson01.aspx.

Comment: If the idea of splitting code off into a common library intrigues you there was a good conversation over at stack exchange where the individual put up a pretty large bounty that's worth a look: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40394/how-do-you-organize-your-projects and if that starts you down the path of increased code quality then Martin Fowler's Refactoring book is a must: http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672